# cannot access env inside nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt v2.12.2 in SPA mode and want to use env variables within the default `head`. I am using `@nuxtjs/dotenv` however when the page is rendered the `baseUrl` is undefined.

I am able to access `BaseUrl` from within page layouts fine, but not from within `nuxt.config.js` like below.

**.env**

```
BASE_URL=https://example.com
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
const env = import('dotenv')
env.config()

export default {
  mode: 'spa',

  generate: {
    fallback: true
  },

  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  },

  head: {
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'og:image',
        name: 'og:image',
        content: process.env.baseUrl + '/og/facebook.png'
      }
    ],
  },

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ]

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.env.baseUrl` is not yet set when the `head` property is set.

One solution is to use a **function** for `head`, which would be run after the `env` is setup:

```js
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.$route?.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'og:image',
          name: 'og:image',
          content: process.env.baseUrl + '/og/facebook.png'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to access $route inside head() in the nuxt.config.js? eg `content: process.env.baseUrl + this.$route.path`

Comment: @Simon Yes, use a normal function instead, which would let you do `content: process.env.baseUrl + this.$route?.path`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above (using a function for the head) didn't work for me, but this did:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env

If you use NUXT_ENV_ then the env variables are available at build time and can be used in the head!